# Ckan popular dataset flame icon does not appear

Tags: python, ckan

Ckan has Page View Tracking feature, that counts dataset and resources views. By default flame icon should appear next to dataset title when it has more than 10 views. So in my case flame icon does appear next to resource title when it reaches min views number, but does not appear next to dataset title.

Ckan version is 2.8.2.

I added "ckan.tracking_enabled = true" to ckan config file.
I made sure that views are actually counted through api package_show() function. 
After i started to research scripts that are responsible for this function. 
As far as I know, package_item.html snippet is responsible for datasets.

This block is responsible for the flame icon to appear:

```py
{% snippet 'snippets/package_item.html', package=c.datasets[0] %}

...

{{ h.popular('recent views', package.tracking_summary.recent, min=10) if package.tracking_summary }}
```

I found out that tracking_summary property is not presented in package object and that's why flame icon does not appear.

At the same time in resource_item.html file we have res.tracking_summary that is presented and contain actual numbers of views, and when minimal condition is met we can see flame icon next to resource title.

So the question is why 'package' object does not contain 'tracking summary'?

Comment: Just connecting with the issue created  and the discussion there https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues/4972#issuecomment-530619868